# Azure AAD authentication for Web API giving 401 with message invalid_grant

Tags: azure-active-directory, owin, asp.net-authentication

i am calling an external REST API which uses AAD based authentication
I am using the access token generated for a service principal (app registration) in my tenant and I have granted appropriate permission/admin consent to my app on the permission defined by external API.

i generate the access token using endpoint "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{aadtenantId}/oauth2/token" and grant_Type of client_credentials and appropriate audience.

external API is using WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions([doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/dn385594(v=vs.113))) to validate the incoming token.

when I call API with above token it returns 401 with message “Invalid authorization bearer is passed (invalid_grant)”.

how can i know what is the option in  WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions that controls the grant_type to be validated for token. trying to understand what is the grant_type external API has configured to allow. I have the access to source code of external API, and i don't see anything in the code that controls/validate grant_type.

Comment: Can you include the parameters and the API permissions you are using to generate the token?

Comment: client_id = "", client_secret="", grant_type=''client_credentials", resource=""   these are the key-value  i pass for x-www-form-urlencode to API https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/token

Comment: doesn't look like it helps. my scenrio is specific to appid token (and not user token) and destination service is using WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions to validate the token

Comment: The error `invalid_grant` usually occurs if you are passing invalid/wrong scope while generating the access token. Check the scope and try

Comment: Ok, presently i am not using any scope while creating token. In call to AAD for generation of token, i am passing grant_type.. let me try to get more clarity if service is expecting any specific scope

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results like below:***

I created an Azure AD Application and Exposed the API:

[image]

I generated the Access Token with below parameters:

```json
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
grant_type:client_credentials
resource:api://ClientID
```

[image]

To validate the token, make sure to configure the **`UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication`** class like below:

```cs
public class Startup
{
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
ConfigureAuth(app);
}
private void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
{
Tenant = "TenantURL",   //XXX.onmicrosoft.com   
TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
{
ValidAudience = "ApplicationIDURL" //api://ClientID
}
});
}
```

The error ***"**401 Invalid authorization bearer is passed (invalid_grant)**"*** usually occurs if you are passing wrong/invalid resource or scope. Try generating the token with valid resource and try.

If still the issue persists, try using **`v2.0` Endpoint** to generate the token like below:

```json
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
grant_type:client_credentials
scope:api://ClientID/.default
```

[image]

Comment: I agree with Rukmini's v2.0 endpoint solution but I'd like to add that if you go that way you must change the accessTokenAcceptedVersion from null to 2 in the app registration's manifest.